# Map is displayed only if I wait at least 1 minute

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have `view1` in which there is `button1`, when the user click on `button 1`, the current location of the user is tracked and a second view `view2` is shown where the user set his search parameters and click on `button2`, when `button2` clicked, a view `view3` is shown where a Map is displayed.

Now my problem is if the user wait 1 minute at least before clicking on `button2`, the Map is shown pretty well, otherwise the Map is not displayed.
My relevant code for `view2` is :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
//when this view is loaded, the user current location is tracked
        self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    #pragma mark-
    #pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate
    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
    fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
        float latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        float longitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        TopStationAppDelegate *topStation=(TopStationAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        topStation.latitudeUtilisateur=latitude;
        topStation.longitudeUtilisateur=longitude;
        NSLog(@"%f",latitude);
        NSLog(@"%f",longitude);
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    }
```

my code in `view3` which make problem :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
//here is the problem:
//if the user wait 1 minute before coming to this view, I mean before clicking on button2
//this view shows the map pretty well, otherwise the map is not displayed and I got brown //screen  

    [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    TopStationAppDelegate *topStation=(TopStationAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication      sharedApplication]delegate];
    latitudeOfUserLocation=topStation.latitudeUtilisateur;
    longitudeOfUserLocation=topStation.longitudeUtilisateur;
}
```

Why should I wait 1 minute, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to show the user location based on the code provided. You have created a `CLLocationManager` instance and asked it to update the user's current location. This is bound to take some time before the delegate method is called. You set the app delegate's `topStation.latitudeUtilisateur` and `topStation.longitudeUtilisateur` in the delegate method.

Suppose the user moves on to the next screen before these values are retrieved, the values above wouldn't be set. You accessed the data in the `-viewWillAppear` before they are set and hence would get stale or `nil` data. Trying to show this location would not work properly.

If you really wish to display the user's location, can't you afford to use`MKMapView`'s `showsUserLocation`. Set this to `YES` and handle the location update in the delegate's `-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method.

Let me know if I misunderstood your problem.